# How can I loopback only Line-in with a headphone that has no microphone?

Tags: pulseaudio, loop-device

I've been using `loopback` module for some time and it all works except when I plug a headphone without a microphone. when I plug a headphone without a microphone the system sound is "loopbacked" making a weird echo.

I'm using the commands

```
pactl load-module module-loopback
pactl unload-module module-loopback
alsamixer
```

Apparently the `loopback` driver is taking system sounds because there is no microphone.

So I want to permanently set loopback and taking specifically the input from Line-in with `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

Also I don't know where is pulse audio documentation to write this configuration files.